# How to monitor many CLCircularRegions

Tags: ios, swift

I am building booking app, and I need to send a notification to users when they enter a region that has a space available for booking. I can create a region for space location and start responding when a user enters that region. but what if I have too many spaces available for booking? How could I keep tracking of all that regions?

Comment: The better approach for that is keep tracking only the nearest places, only 20 places will be tracked so you should handle this wisely

Comment: yeah, so should I start mentoring nearest 20 locations once the user opens the app?

Comment: I think that is the better way to do this, and of course every time you get new location info update that 20 nearest places tracking accordingly, its hard to do it but that is the idea for that. Anyway there are some frameworks that do this but... As i remember all of them are payed

Comment: It's not too hard, I will do it! thanks @ReinierMelian

Comment: Make one of the 20 regions a region around your current position with a radius according to your needs (probably just big enough to  include the 19 other regions). Then update when leaving this region. Maybe additionally register for `significantLocationChanges` to be able to update the regions in case the geofencing did not fire. Which will happen regularly.